# Speed up cursor in macvim with janus

Tags: vim, macvim

I have MacVim installed and want to increase the speed by which the cursor moves about the screen. In other words, I want the cursor to move faster when I click on the arrow keys or h,j,k, and l. What command do I add, and which file do I add it to? (.vimrc, .vimrc.after, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to drop Janus which is full of settings and plugins (30) that you probably don't use/need. Or, at the very least, review all of the decisions made for you by complete strangers and remove/reset anything you don't need.

A better solution (in the long term) would be to learn about motions and text-objects: for anything other than very short movements `hjkl` and the arrows are equally useless when you get used to `bBeEwW^$fFtT{}()[]<C-f><C-b>/?` and so on.

As I like to say, `:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.

Or `$ vimtutor`, actually. Did you do it?